# How to use @defer in angular component many times in the same page

Tags: angular, deferred

Can I use @defer on multiple viewports in the same page? When I use it, all the defers work at the same time, not waiting to enter the viewport to execute. They all get triggered in the beginning.

Can I use a defer for each one?
To load each component when it enters the viewport?

How can I achieve this? Please provide a code example for a simple response.

Comment: What do you mean "multiple viewports"? The viewport is the window as far as I know, and there's only one.

Comment: i mean use @defer many times in one page

Answer (score 0):

You can use this template:

```html
<app-text/>

@for (n of [1,2,3]; track $index) {
  @defer (on viewport) {
    <app-text/>
  } @placeholder {
    <p>loading...</p>
  }
}
```

To create `app-text`, you can run `ng g c text` and within the template insert enough content to fill the viewport.

If you use VS Code, you can type an [Emmet abbreviation](https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/lorem-ipsum/) like `lorem1000` followed by TAB or ENTER. This will generate 1000 words using Emmet's "Lorem Ipsum" generator.

As you scroll down, you should see the scrollbar handle jumping up.